# Error 403 when trying to export a Databricks Workspace

Tags: powershell, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm facing an issue when trying to export to local path. This is the code (after connecting to Azure with my account)

```
Export-DatabricksWorkspaceItem -Path $ExportPath -LocalPath $LocalPath -Format DBC
```

And this is the error I get

```
Error 403 Invalid access token.  HTTP ERROR 403 Problem accessing /api/2.0/workspace/export. Reason:     Invalid access token.
```

I tried using `Get-DatabricksWorkspaceItem` to list it but I'm facing the same error. I'm using `PowerShell 7.2.9`. Tried to pass `-apiKey` or a `-Token`created in Databricks with my account but those parameters do not exist.

Comment: You are having a credential issue and need to setup OAUTH.  See  following : https://docs.thoughtspot.com/cloud/latest/connections-databricks-oauth?force_isolation=true

Comment: hello @jdweng, I've found a simpler solution (answer below) but thanks for the proposal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `DatabricksPS` module is not working in `PowerShell 7.X.X`. Instead, I've found other module called `PSAzureDatabricks` that have the method `Export-AzureDatabricksContent`.

If someone is strugling with this, [here is the documentation link](https://github.com/igs-opensource/PSAzureDatabricks#:%7E:text=Export%2DAzureDatabricksContent%20%2DConnection%20%24Connection%20%2DPath%20%22/SomeDirectory%22%20%2DToFile%20Archive.zip)